# "Editing" Android app

Tags: android, gps

I would like to remove a line of code from OpenGPSTracker source (to turn off the annoying alarm), but am unsure what steps I would have to take to compile and transfer to my (un-rooted) device.

Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out the project source: http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/checkout
2. Remove the line of code
3. Let Eclipse build the project
4. Run the project on your device (and it will be there until you remove it)

If you want the APK file:

1. Go into your project directory into the "bin" directory
2. Take the apk file there and install it on your device

Tip: Installation from unknown source has to be enabled on your device.